# Implementing Mergesort in Ruby Recursively

Tags: ruby, recursion, mergesort

I've been teaching myself programming over the last few months and I'm finally up to recursion. Right now, I'm supposed to implement `Mergesort` recursively. I've done my research and understand what is supposed to be happening, but I am having some issues with my code. At this point, I don't want to just look up the answer because I'm more interested in figuring out what I doing wrong, rather than just having the answer. I keep getting a no method error saying

> undefined method `>' for [6]:Array

My code at the moment is such:

```
def merge_sort(arr)
  n = arr.length
  p = n/2
  q = p - 1
  return arr if n == 1

  l1 = arr[0..q]
  l2 = arr[p..n]

  l1 = merge_sort(l1)
  l2 = merge_sort(l2)

  return merge(l1, l2)
end

def merge(arr_1, arr_2)
  arr_3 = []
  while !arr_1.empty? && !arr_2.empty?
    if arr_1[0] > arr_2[0]
      arr_3 << arr_2[0]
      arr_2.delete_at(0)
    else
      arr_3 << arr_1[0]
      arr_1.delete_at(0)
    end
  end

  if arr_1.length == 0
    arr_3 << arr_2[0..-1]
  elsif arr_2.length == 0
    arr_3 << arr_1[0..-1]
  end

  arr_3
end

puts merge_sort([2, 6, 4, 5, 7, 9, 8, 3])
```

Comment: I'm guessing the error is pointing to `if arr_1[0] > arr_2[0]`.  Try using the gem `pry` to debug.  At the top of the document `require 'pry'`, then right before that line add `binding.pry` and run from the terminal. You will then be able to type `arr_1` and `arr_2` to see the values of these variables

Comment: Please format/align the code with 2-spaces indent to make it readable. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I had tried something similar by doing p arr_1 as well as p arr_1[0] before the while loop and 6 was coming back as a fixnum and not an array, but I will try what you suggested as well!

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr_3` contains array of arrays.  You need to flatten it in the last line of `merge` method

```
arr_3.flatten
```

---

Also, I would recommend to use variable names that helps in understanding methods.  You should also look at various methods that [`Array`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html) class has to offer as some of it can be useful in writing concise code.  For example, below is one attempt to rewrite your `merge` method keeping the logic same as what you have.  Here we avoided `arr_3` getting become array of array by using [`Array#concat`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-concat) method

```
def merge(left, right)

  merged_array = []
  while !left.empty? && !right.empty?
    if left.first > right.first
      merged_array << right.shift
    else
      merged_array << left.shift
    end
  end

  if left.empty?
    merged_array.concat right
  else
    merged_array.concat left
  end

  merged_array
end
```